# HP ProLiant SE326M1 not booting from LSI SAS 9211-8i

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sas, lsi

I have taken out the old RAID card in my HP ProLiant SE326M1 server and replaced it with the LSI SAS 9211-8i HBA. I then installed Nexenta community edition onto three of the drives that are attached to the LSI card.

I have set the boot device to the LSI card however when I turn the server on it does not boot into Nexenta which was installed onto the card. Has anyone had problems similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

The HP DL18x25SFF is LUN 0 and is the multiplexer.  If the card can sees your drives you will probably have to set the boot drive as the boot drive in the advanced configuration on the card as normally the boot drive is LUN 0.

Options:
I do not remember if the back-plane has 2 or 4  SATA by passes if it has 4 you could try a FAN cable to by pass the multiplexer (remember set the jumpers!).

Or just buy a P410 off ebay.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting a couple of times and see if it picks up. I'm not sure why you used three disks (triple mirror?), but sometimes the drive enumeration on a backplane like that and the 9211 isn't deterministic.

Edit:

You need to select the boot device in the LSI BIOS as well:

*The 9211-8i is bootable, your BIOS should see any drives connected to it and allow you to select them as a boot device just like as if they were connected to any other SATA port. If not, the LSI bios allows you to select which drives are passed to your system BIOS for booting.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have rebooted a few times and it still does not pick it up. For installing Nexenta what is best practice in regards to installing the OS onto multiple disks?

Comment: A RAID 1 pair is normal. What did YOU do?

Comment: I followed the installer which allows the installation to be split between three disks. I have now installed Nexenta onto only one of the disks but its still not booting into the Nexenta

Comment: You need to set the boot device in the BIOS of the server, as well as in the controller. See my edit.

Comment: The Card is currently set as the boot device in the BIOS. In regards to the BIOS for the LSI card I used Ctrl + C to get into this. This takes me into the BIOS for the card and shows me the adapter list which has the boot order set to 0. I can go into the Adapter itself but from there I get the options "RAID Properties, SAS Technology and Advance Adapter Properties" none of which let me select a drive to boot from.

Comment: It's in SAS topology. Keep lookin'

Comment: Yep I went into the SAS topology however all it shows is one single item "HP DL18x25SFF". None of the disks are shown in that output, I am certain the card picks up the drives and it displays them all on the avago POST message. Should the disks be showing in the SAS Topology menu?

Comment: I don't know. Sorry.